# Strange bug in python code of Euclid's algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a simple python code that computes the greatest common divisor of two integers.

```
def gcd(a,b):
  if (b==0):
    return a
  gcd(b,a%b)
```

This simple code uses the Euclid's algorithm . The problem is that it doesn't return except when b is zero .
what is the source of this bug ?

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: *it doesn't return except when b is zero* the fact that the if b == 0 block has a return statement and the rest of the function doesn't should tell you enough

Comment: Doesn't each recursive function call contain a return statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Add return in recursive call as well.

```
def gcd(a,b):
  if (b==0):
    return a
  return gcd(b,a%b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return function call:

```
def gcd(a,b):
  if (b==0):
    return a
  return gcd(b,a%b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't return the return value of the recursive call.

```
def gcd(a,b):
  if (b==0):
    return a
  return gcd(b,a%b)
```

This should work.